# React Router V6 useParams inside nested routes NOT Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created a custom page with path `"/:name"` inside a nested route. I expected the output to be **Hello, my friend {name}**, instead I am getting an error saying `ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`. How do I fix this?

**Route Page**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomePage from './Pages/HomePage'
import OtherPage from "./Pages/OtherPage"
import ErrorPage from './Pages/ErrorPage'
import MainProduct from "./Pages/projects/MainProduct"
import FirstProduct from "./Pages/projects/otherProduct/FirstProduct"
import SecondProduct from "./Pages/projects/otherProduct/SecondProduct"
import CustomProduct from "./Pages/projects/otherProduct/CustomProduct"
import MainNavComponent from './Components/MainNavComponent'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <MainNavComponent />
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<HomePage />} />
                <Route path='/mainProduct' element={<MainProduct />}>
                    <Route path='firstProduct' element={<FirstProduct />} />
                    <Route path='secondProduct' element={<SecondProduct />} />
                    <Route exact path=":name" element={<CustomProduct />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/otherPage' element={<OtherPage />} />
                <Route path='*' element={<ErrorPage />} />
                <Route exact path=":name" element={<CustomProduct />} />

            </Routes>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Custom Route Page**

```
export default function CustomProduct() {

    let { name } = useParams()

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello, my friend {name}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What's your server made of? I bet that's the problem.

Comment: This is just a localhost server.

Comment: Yes, what is _creating_ the server? Did you create one yourself or are you using something like a VSCode extension or webpack dev server or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
 add  <BrowserRouter> before <Routes> tag and close it( </BrowserRouter>) after </Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for your routes `/mainProduct/{yourname}` because your :name inside `/mainProduct` Route

```
 <Route path='/mainProduct' element={<MainProduct />}>
    <Route path='firstProduct' element={<FirstProduct />} />
    <Route path='secondProduct' element={<SecondProduct />} />
    <Route exact path=":name" element={<CustomProduct />} />
 </Route>
```

try this link `/mainProduct/{yourname}`  such as : `/mainProduct/name1`  or `/mainProduct/name2`